# RaisePropertyChanged<T>(string propertyName, T oldValue, T newValue, bool broadcast)

Tags: .net, mvvm-light

I was trying to get the `RaisePropertyChanged<T>(string propertyName, T oldValue, T newValue, bool broadcast)` working but could not get it to work.

I am not implementing it in any real world scenario but just for learning it. If I raise broadcast the usual way only then it works
`Messenger.Default.Send<PropertyUpdateeMessage>(new PropertyUpdateeMessage("test"));`

So i am wondering what am i missing to use  `RaisePropertyChanged<T>(string propertyName, T oldValue, T newValue, bool broadcast)`

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Raki

Answer (score 15):

This took me a bit to figure out too.  Basically you have to coordinate the message you're registering with the message you're sending, but there isn't a lot of documentation about it.

I have a full working sample [here](http://chriskoenig.net/2010/07/05/mvvm-light-messaging/), but here's the info in a nutshell:

First, register for the PropertyChangedMessage specifying the type that's going on the bus

```
Messenger.Default.Register<PropertyChangedMessage<ObjectICareAbout>>(
    this,
    (action) => DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(
                 () => DoWorkOnObject(action.NewValue) 
                )
);
```

Then send the message out when the main VM's property changes

```
RaisePropertyChanged(SelectedItemPropertyName, oldValue, value, true);
```

There are some disambiguation options you can use when sending out the message and registering to hear it, but this is how the basics work.

Comment: Fantastic!  If you wouldn't mind marking this answer as accepted, that would really help my reputation.